# Remove gravity from accelerometer using rotation vector quaternion

Tags: embedded, sensors, gravity

Please bear with me if this sounds a repeated question. But I just only want to verify if the whole approach I am using is sound. Basically I have constructed the following from what I have read from different sources.

I have an IMU, from which I am getting accelerometer and rotation vector values. The documentation says the following about the rotation vector.

> The rotation vector provides an orientation output that is expressed as a quaternion referenced to magnetic north
>   and gravity. It is produced by fusing the outputs of the accelerometer, gyroscope and magnetometer. The rotation
>   vector is the most accurate orientation estimate available.

The rotation vector quaternion tells how much the device has rotated from the earth's coordinate system. I wanted to get Linear Acceleration on the device's coordinate system from the combination of the rotation vector and the accelerometer. And I am assuming that whenever the device is at rest the linear acceleration should be 0.

This is the math I came up with.

- get the quaternion from rotation vector `q`
- get the inverse of the quaternion so that the gravity would be expressed on the device's coordinate system. `qPrime = inverse(q)`
- take the median of the norm of about certain number of acceleration signals. `norm`
- create gravity vector as `g = [0 0 norm]`
- get linear acceleration as `a_linear = a_total - qPrime*g*conjugate(qPrime)`

roughly here are the important lines in my matlab/octave code.

```matlab
    %get the gravity norm at rest from 100 samples
    gNorm = median(sqrt(sum(Acc(1:100, 1:3).^2, 2)), 1);
    %a couple of lines and a loop later
    q_inv = qInv(q);
    a_p = qTimes(qTimes(q_inv, [0 g]), qConj(q_inv));
    LinAcc = [Acc(i, 1:3) - a_p(2:4)];
```

After using the above code I have a plot that looks like the following.

[image: linear acceleration plot]

Is any of my assumptions wrong? Am I wrong to assume that I must use the inverse of the quaternion to rotate to the device's coordinate system? Should I think errors such as 0.05m/s/s in the y come from other sources like calibration and not from the math?

Comment: I'm not quite following this, but if you wish to know the acceleration of the device, you only need the accelerometer and the knowledge of which direction that's down. Anyway, this doesn't seem to be a programming question, but a physics/math question.

Comment: I am trying to get which direction is down using quaternions, which can be interpreted as [down when seen from the device] and [down when seen from earth] kind. Probably this fits well in the math, you are right.

Comment: The way I've done that in the past is to simply use calibration when the device is at rest. The acceleration vector will be 1G and from there you get a default value for all 3 axis.

Answer (score 0):

The equation is correct. The spiking noises are little bit weird. Did you check the value before the removal of gravity multiplication? If the original acc values have the same noises that is not from your math. Or it could be your rotation vector noise.